# Edit Data in Table

Tags: php

I have a table with an edit button(1 per each product) that when clicked I want it to edit that particular row..

This is my table

```
<?php
    require 'connect.php';

    $query = $link->query("SELECT * FROM fornecedor");

    echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='2' cellspacing='2'";

    echo "<tr>
            <td>Nome</td>
            <td>NIF</td>
            <td>Cidade</td>
            <td>Rua</td>
            <td>NrPorta</td>
            <td>Website</td>
            <td>email</td>
            <td>Editar</td>
            <td>Eliminar</td>
            <td>Adicionar</td>
        </tr>"; 

        while ($row = $query->fetch_array() ) {

            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $row["Nome"] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row["NIF"] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row["Cidade"] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row["Rua"] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row["NrPorta"] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row["Website"] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row["Email"] . "</td>";
            echo "<td><a href='editarFornecedor.php'><img src='images/edit.svg' width='40px' height='30px'></a></td>";
            echo "<td><a href='eliminarFornecedor.php'><img src='images/delete.png' width='30px' height='30px'></a></td>";
            echo "</tr>";  
        };
          echo "</table>";

          $link->close();

?>
```

And this is my edit page:

```
include 'connect.php';

$result = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM Fornecedor");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))

?>

  <form method="post" action="edit_data.php">
  <input type="text" name="id" value="<?php echo "$row[id]"?>">
    <tr>        
      <td>Nome</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="Nome" size="40" value="<?php echo "$row[Nome]"?>">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Nif</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="Nif" size="40"  value="<?php echo "$row[NIF]"?>">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cidade</td>
      <td>
       <input type="text" name="Cidade" size="40" value="<?php echo "$row[Cidade]"?>">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Rua</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="Rua" size="40" value="<?php echo "$row[Rua]"?>">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>NrPorta</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="NrPorta" size="40"  value="<?php echo "$row[NrPorta]"?>">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Website</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="Website" size="40"  value="<?php echo "$row[Website]"?>">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Email</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="Email" size="40" value="<?php echo "$row[Email]"?>">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="right">
        <input type="submit" name="submit value" value="Edit">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </form>
  </table>


<?php mysqli_close($link);?>
```

I only see the form without values , and i wanted to make them visible so the user can edit the data. What am i doing wrong ? bad coding or something missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of your `$row` values are something like this:

```
$row[Nome]
```

When they should have single quotes like this:

```
$row['Nome']
```

Additionally your `echo` lines within the HTML are like this:

```
<input type="text" name="Email" size="40" value="<?php echo "$row[Email]"?>">
```

But those `"` double quotes are not needed, so it should be like this:

```
<input type="text" name="Email" size="40" value="<?php echo $row['Email'] ?>">
```

Here is my attempt to clean up the issues mentioned above. I believe it should work:

```
  <form method="post" action="edit_data.php">
  <input type="text" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['id'] ?>">
    <tr>        
      <td>Nome</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="Nome" size="40" value="<?php echo $row['Nome'] ?>">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Nif</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="Nif" size="40"  value="<?php echo $row['NIF'] ?>">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cidade</td>
      <td>
       <input type="text" name="Cidade" size="40" value="<?php echo $row['Cidade'] ?>">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Rua</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="Rua" size="40" value="<?php echo $row['Rua'] ?>">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>NrPorta</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="NrPorta" size="40"  value="<?php echo $row['NrPorta'] ?>">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Website</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="Website" size="40"  value="<?php echo $row['Website'] ?>">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Email</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="Email" size="40" value="<?php echo $row['Email'] ?>">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="right">
        <input type="submit" name="submit value" value="Edit">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </form>
  </table>
```

Comment: You missed one ;) (first input element)

Comment: Let's hope this one's not another can of "you know what" ;-)

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to put the name of the array-objects in quotes.

instead of:

```
$row[Email]
```

try:

```
$row['Email']
```

and so on.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you forgot to use the quotes for your `$row['']`'s on your edit page!

Oh, and also I don't see how you get the ID again on the next page by using `$row['']`.. try linking with a query string:

`/editarFornecedor.php?id=" . $row['id'] . "`

Then, on the edit page, use the ID to find the row the user wants to edit:

`$_GET['id']`, make that a variable and use it on your `input` tag! Also, you might add `disable` on that input!

Answer (score 0):

on your edit button, put the id of your row

```
echo "<td><a href='editarFornecedor.php?id={$row['id']}'><img src='images/edit.svg' width='40px' height='30px'></a></td>";
```

in edit page, receive the id and get the row relative to this

```
if (!isset($_GET['id'])) {
    throw new Exception('Supplier ID not supplied');
}

$id = mysqli_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);

$result = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM Fornecedor WHERE id = $id");
```

Then remove the `while` because you get only one row

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
```

Comment: Yeah, i was missing that part , i tried like you said but it keeps telling me that id is and undifined index. Should id be the primary key of my table ?

Comment: @user3727136 yep, the `id` is the primary key of your table!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<?=` to echoe single values. For example, `Hello <?=$name?>!`.

You also might use quotes to address items that are identified by strings in your array. For example, `$row['id']`. PHP will implicitly covert text with no spaces to string, but it's always a good practice to put string data inside quotes.

```
  <form method="post" action="edit_data.php">
  <input type="text" name="id" value="<?=$row['id']?>">
    <tr>        
      <td>Nome</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="Nome" size="40" value="<?=$row['Nome']?>">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Nif</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="Nif" size="40"  value="<?=$row['NIF']?>">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cidade</td>
      <td>
       <input type="text" name="Cidade" size="40" value="<?=$row['Cidade']?>">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Rua</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="Rua" size="40" value="<?=$row['Rua']?>">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>NrPorta</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="NrPorta" size="40"  value="<?=$row['NrPorta']?>">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Website</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="Website" size="40"  value="<?=$row['Website]']?>">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Email</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="Email" size="40" value="<?=$row['Email']?>">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="right">
        <input type="submit" name="submit value" value="Edit">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </form>
  </table>
```